# WPF: Customizing message boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the joy of having to develop an application using a customized CI style; at the widget level, the color/style adaptation can be done using `ControlTemplates`, but how can I customize the look of the standard message boxes (i.e. `System.Windows.MessageBox`)? (I acknowledge the fact that the file open dialog etc. cannot be customized.)

Comment: As far as I know, you will need to create a custom message box, you might even be able to get away with inheriting from `MessageBox`.

Comment: @Mike: `MessageBox` is sealed but I agree with the customization part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageBox is a system dialog box and thus can't be styled either. If you need a modal dialog box styled then create a regular window, set `WindowStyle="None"` and display it with `ShowDialog()`.

Answer (score 1):

Standard windows message box are good for that.Although you can customize your Message box but not to a great extent

check out this link  [WPF MessageBox - Custom control](http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2009/12/wpf-messagebox-custom-control.html)

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2011/05/26/a-customizable-wpf-messagebox/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of how you can do it with vanilla WPF, but you could use the WPF Extended Toolkit. See here for examples: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessageBox

The free community edition includes the MessageBox.